# Sass syntax highlighting for TextMate2 not working

Tags: textmatebundles, textmate2

I'm using TM2 and I love it. Sadly, the syntax highlighting for Sass doesn't really seem to work. Is it only me?

For example, create a new "xxx.sass" file with the following content:

```
+h5bp-normalize // All normalize styles
+h5bp-main      // Basic styles ( see variables partial)
```

In my TM2, the 2nd line is colored as if it were a comment, but it definitely isn't one. Can anybody verify this? Is there any solution? I'm starting the HTML/CSS implementation of a big project right now, and I'd like to use Sass instead of SCSS (I read a lot about which one to choose, so please don't tell me that SCSS is the standard now), but without proper syntax highlighting this seems impossible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I found that the https://github.com/nathos/sass-textmate-bundle/ bundle seems to be working.

To install (I also tried opening the Sass.tmbundle, and although TM2 asked me whether I want to install the bundle, it didn't seem to work):

```
mkdir -p ~/Library/Application\ Support/Avian/Bundles/
cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/Avian/Bundles/
git clone https://github.com/nathos/sass-textmate-bundle.git Sass.tmbundle
```

Maybe reload TM2.

Answer (score 1):

When I used the .sass format in Sublime Text 2 I found that it was not auto recognizing the syntax and that I had to set it manually (unlike any other format I've encountered). Are you saying that even after setting the syntax highlighting it won't work?

There are several packages for syntax highlighting, trying another one might be a quick fix. Which one are you using?

Comment: I set it manually, too, but didn't change a thing. I'm using "Ruby Sass" which is baked right into TM2. Where can I find more packages?  I also tried https://github.com/adamstac/sass-textmate-bundle and https://github.com/seaofclouds/sass-textmate-bundle which both don't seem to load in TM2...